# how to sent my current latlong to other user?

Tags: android

im creating an application i want to sent my current lat long to other user using any service but i dont have any server side application i have only user side application how i will sent my lat long to other user which use same application with out using any server? what do ido??

how to sent my current latlong to other user?? without using   server url

i just simple want to sent my current latlong to other user he also use same application

Comment: what did you try or consider so far? Did you try to break the problem into parts? How do you know which users you want to send data to??

Answer (score 0):

You might have several possibilities. One of them is creating a `Socket` from one to other. This has the disadvantage that you *need* to know the destination IP address, which in turn raises other problems: Several mobile ISPs in some countries assign the same IP address to several mobile devices, if the user's using *WiFi*, you might crash into some Firewall problem.

Another way is via `Bluetooth`. This, however, needs the two devices be fairly close to interchange the information.

Summarizing: The best way is indeed using a third-party server somewhere in the internet and use it as a web-service, that's the best way how you can change information between devices.

Answer (score 0):

You send it via SMS. Another end user app have to read the incoming SMS, Which is related with latlong they can update them UI

Comment: This idea costs much and it has limitation due to Tri rule.

Comment: There is no other way. (without using server url- Socket also need the url)

Comment: If the user is near by you you can send via bluetooth.If he is near to you there is no need to send. you can tell latlong value directly to another end user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sockets

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html

Implement a ServerSocket in one side and connect to it in the other side, devices should be connected over the Internet of a wifi network

Comment: how give me example please

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Third party server` and [`GCM`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/&ei=lM5PU-TpM6jX0QXKv4CQCQ&usg=AFQjCNF2_kLbCOrQzUknyZhTpTlQ4-NBnA&sig2=FV_3hNOcKFmMYWr5KuXYww&bvm=bv.64764171,d.d2k). Register all your users to The third party server, then send your `LatLong` to the server which will relay it to the user identified by the `GCM registration ID`